# DataGridView editing cells on WinForms

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, editing, cells

I have a Windows Form VS2010 .NET 4 project with a standard DataGridView bound to a datasource on a form.

The grid has a text column that I want to be a point and edit at the character clicked to.
Like normal textbox/editors when you click on the character you want to adjust.  If possible I would also like to use the UP/DOWN keys to move between rows but would like the cursor to move to the same character position obviously in the same column without selecting the entire text.

I have tried a few things:

DataGridView1.ClearSelection()

DataGridView1.BeginEdit(False)

The BeginEdit just puts the cursor at the end of the text, which means another click to point to the character position for editing.

I know a Commercial grid like DevExpress defaults to editing in which you can click to the correct character position with one click but obviously costs money.

I have tried in the DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing event

```
If TypeOf e.Control Is System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl Then
        Dim tb As TextBox = e.Control
        tb.SelectionStart = 5
        tb.SelectionLength = 5
End If
```

But this does nothing.

I am just trying to remove the two or three clicks to get to the character position that needs adjustment.

I haven't looked at a Custom DataColumn as yet.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good out of the box way of doing this. The closest there is is to set the `EditMode` of the grid to `EditOnEnter` but that means you only need two clicks, not three.

You will need to write your own column type.

Someone has done just that [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/fe5d5cfb-63b6-4a69-a01c-b7bbd18ae84a).

I haven't checked if that example handles up and down - if it doesn't then you were on the right track with the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties, just grab the caret position of the cell you are leaving and apply it to the new cell.

---

It turns out that setting these properties is a little bit more involved that I remembered (possibly because I was already using a MaskedTextBox custom column type last time I did this).

The code below (in c# but the principle holds for vb.Net and I can give the vb code if you can't convert it yourself) works happily - could be tidied up by putting it into a custom control but I'll leave that as an exercise :)

First I add a handler for the EditingControlShowing event:

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl t = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
    current_control = t;
    t.Leave += new EventHandler(t_Leave);
}
```

In the method above current_control is a form level private variable. The event handler for t looks like this:

```
void t_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cell_caret_pos = current_control.SelectionStart;
}
```

There again we have a class level private field - cell_caret_pos.

Then what I found was that to set SelectionStart and SelectionLength you need to work within the CellEnter event handler:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
    DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl editControl =
        (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)dataGridView1.EditingControl;

    if (cell_caret_pos != 0)
    {
        editControl.SelectionStart = cell_caret_pos;
        editControl.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer does the main bit, I had been searching for this for ages.  It doesn't do the up down bit, but I might be able to amend it.  Any ideas on getting the previous cell.

Comment: I just proof of concepted this very quickly by placing the editing contrl (from editing control showing) in a form level private variable then also placing the SelectionStart value in a form level int variable during the editing control leave event. Then once outside of the grid I checked the int and it had the last editing control position. Only took me a minute to test so you should be able to place something similar into that example's subclassed dgv quite easily.

Comment: Thanks David, I have the caret position but when the up/down arrow is used it doesn't go into edit mode on the next row, I am not sure how to set editing and then reposition the caret.  I tried setting EditMode to EditOnEnter but this prevents the one click edit for the mouse.  Sorry bit of a newbie...

Comment: Thanks again David, this works I just need to fix it with the one click editing i.e. when the cell_caret_pos has been set the mouse cell enter event occurs after the mouse click and it overrides the original position from the click; fixed my issue above by setting cell_caret_pos (in the OnMouseDown event) to -1 and putting an if around the cell enter lines.  The only thing I don't like is the painting between cell row moves, it goes white and then shows the text, but this is a minor thing.  Many thanks to David for his assistance.